# how to view ROR App in Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, localhost

```
$ rails server -e development
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:90: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:92: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1188: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1446: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1541: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1448: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1543: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1501: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1596: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1555: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1650: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1562: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1657: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[59285] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[59285] * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[59285] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[59285] * Environment: development
[59285] * Process workers: 1
[59285] * Preloading application
[59285] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[59285] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[59285] - Worker 0 (pid: 59305) booted, phase: 0
source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=5000ms     state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=5000ms     service=1ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=15000ms service=1ms state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=15000ms service=0ms state=active
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2018-06-13 15:19:51 -0500
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations"     ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-    5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 7.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=15000ms service=88ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=a30cb83a-2e51-4b0c-b4eb-b70e7007e994 timeout=15000ms service=90ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=5000ms state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=5000ms service=0ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=15000ms service=0ms state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=15000ms service=0ms state=active
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2018-06-13 15:20:01 -0500
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (2.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=15000ms service=16ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=70869e53-6fb0-4862-995f-eb7cbc63cbf0 timeout=15000ms service=17ms state=completed
```

[image]

How to I get to the ROR app. Like it looks like the live site.

https://pcms.herokuapp.com/login

The app was designed by a previous developer in 2013. I just received the files two weeks ago. Having to update everything to latest versions of everything. I've added the database into the pgAdmin4.

I need to be able to see the changes in the localhost before pushing to heroku platform.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get 'welcome/index'

resources :feedbacks, only: [:post]
```

YES I am in the App Directory

EDITED

```
$bin/rails s
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:90: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::VERSION
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:92: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1188: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::S_IF_DOOR
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1267: warning: previous definition of S_IF_DOOR was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1446: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::DIRECTORY_TERM
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1541: warning: previous definition of DIRECTORY_TERM was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1448: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::Entry_::SYSCASE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1543: warning: previous definition of SYSCASE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1501: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::OPT_TABLE
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1596: warning: previous definition of OPT_TABLE was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1555: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LOW_METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1650: warning: previous definition of LOW_METHODS was here
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/fileutils.rb:1562: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::METHODS
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/fileutils-1.1.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1657: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.4, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[62183] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[62183] * Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[62183] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[62183] * Environment: development
[62183] * Process workers: 1
[62183] * Preloading application
[62183] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[62183] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[62183] - Worker 0 (pid: 62203) booted, phase: 0
source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=5000ms         state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=5000ms service=1ms state=active
source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=15000ms service=1ms state=ready
source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=15000ms service=4ms state=active
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2018-06-13 20:28:22 -0500
   (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER     BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (3.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=15000ms service=84ms state=completed
source=rack-timeout id=9a3731c3-b99e-49b9-8e7e-026d791a8879 timeout=15000ms service=86ms state=completed
```

Comment: Your screenshot is of an newly created rails app not an existing application. Did you try running `bin/rails s` in the directory of the other application? What's the output...

Comment: You have to be in the correct directory.  Then you have to bundle install and migrate your database.  Then you may run `rails server`

Comment: any ideas on how to get my localhost to look like the live application?